# Is it correct to say "you're holding the book upside-down, turn it right-side up" in this specific situation?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

In the first picture, you're holding the book upside down. The book is perpendicular to the floor and parallel to your face. I think it is correct to say "**you're holding the book upside-down**".

But suppose that you do the same thing but this time the book is parallel to the floor and perpendicular to your face.

Is it still correct to say "**you're holding the book upside-down, turn it right-side up**"?

or maybe "**you're holding the book frontside-back, turn it right-side front**"?

Comment: It doesn't matter, the book is being rotated on the same axis in both scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upside-down in this context is relative to how your eyes would read it; if you were in microgravity or something, and *you* were upside down (relative to the observer) and the *book* were rightside up (relative to the observer), I still think it would be correct (and the least confusing) to say your first sentence. It is upside-down in relation to where it needs to be.